# Multiple custom authentication with spring security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a spring application which uses a custom Authentication Filter say filter1 to authorize the request, this filter uses an authentication manager for authentication and is applicable for all urls in application.

Now, I want to implement a different Authentication Filter say filter2 which has to authorize special kind of request say with url (/api/). That is the all the request which has the url like (/api/**) has to use filter2.

Below is the code I've tried so far for this purpose.

```
public class SecurityAppConfig {

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class APISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private CustomAuthenticationManager1 manager1 = new CustomAuthenticationManager1();

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
      .formLogin().disable().csrf().disable().cors().disable().logout().disable();

  if (manager1 != null) {
    http.addFilterAfter(new Filter1(manager1),
        AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);

  }

}
}


@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class OtherApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private AuthenticationManager2 manager2 = new AuthenticationManager2();

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
      .formLogin().disable().csrf().disable().cors().disable().logout().disable();

  if (manager2 != null) {
    http.antMatchers("/api/**").addFilterAfter(new Filter2(manager2),
        AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
}

}
```

At the time of app start up both the filter are getting registered with their manager but when this ("/api/**") request comes it goes to the first filter for authentication but never goes to the second filter. If I remove the first filter then it works properly but that would override the filters for other api request.

Below is how I've implemented managers and filters

```
public class Filter1 extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
  //implementation omitted for brevity.
}

public class Filter2 extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
  //implementation omitted for brevity.
}

public class AuthenticationManager1 implements AuthenticationManager {
   //implementation omitted for brevity.
}

 public class AuthenticationManager2 implements AuthenticationManager {
   //implementation omitted for brevity.
}
```

Any thoughts on how can I get this working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you need two configs for your case. And I don't see why you need to implement your own authentication manager, even two of them. I guess you should use shared authentication manager instead, implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` (one for each type of authentication), and implement youe own authentication tokens. Besides that, since you're using `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` as a base class for you filters - you can set `filterProcessesUrl` into it, so your filter knows to which URL's it should be applied. So, in brief:

**Authentication Tokens:**

```
public class MyAuth1AuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    // Implementation depends on you auth scheme (you can look on 
    // `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` for example)
}

public class MyAuth2AuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    // ...
}
```

**Authentication Providers:**

```
public class MyAuth1AuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
        // Implementation really depends on you auth scheme (you can look on 
        // `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` for example)
    }        

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // By this we're saying that this auth provider is responsible for our MyAuth1 auth request 
        return (MyAuth1AuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}

public class MyAuth2AuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
        // ...
    }        

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (MyAuth2AuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

**Filters:**

```
public class Auth1Filter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public Auth1Filter(AuthenticationManager authManager, String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        // extract user info here
        // ...

        // populate auth request with your info
        MyAuth1AuthenticationToken authRequest = new MyAuth1AuthenticationToken(...);

        // authenticate
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}

public class Auth2Filter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public Auth2Filter(AuthenticationManager authManager, String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        // extract user info here
        // ...

        // populate auth request with your info
        MyAuth2AuthenticationToken authRequest = new MyAuth1AuthenticationToken(...);

        // authenticate
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

**Security Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    // registering our providers
    auth
        .authenticationProvider(new MyAuth1AuthenticationProvider())
        .authenticationProvider(new MyAuth2AuthenticationProvider());   
}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
           .formLogin().disable()
           .csrf().disable()
           .cors().disable()
           .logout().disable();

        AuthenticationManager authManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);

        http.addFilterAfter(new Auth1Filter(authManager, "/**"), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(new Auth2Filter(authManager, "/api/**"), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Problem is I am extending the legacy code in which it implements the Authenticaton Manager for custom authenticatication, now if I don't create a new config by extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter then I am forced to use the already implemented manager which authenticates request on different logic, therefore I had to create a new config registering filter with new manager but when a API request comes it never goes to filter of the second config.

I tried implementing the second config based on the approach you suggested but 'http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class)' returns null.

Comment: Got your point of not having two configuration as The Spring Security filter contains a list of filter chains, and dispatches a request to the first chain that matches it so in my case it was always dispatching to first chain. (https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/). But can you help me understand why it is wrong to have more than one manager and why springSecurityFilterChain bean expects only one authentication manager bean?