# Multiple authentification strategies in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, token

In order to use a custom authentification in spring security you got to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and override the `loadUserByUsername` method, such as the example below

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String useremail)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userDao.findByUserEmail(useremail);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName or Password Invalid.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled(), true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(userDao.getUserRole(user.getUsersId())));
    }
```

and its working fine for the whole website.

what i want to do now is to expose a restful webservice from the same host and all the requests for that WS will be through the `/api/**` with a different type of authentification (e.g : using tokens) 
is it possible to do it? and if so, is there any idea how to do it ? any useful resources ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making security configuration class as follows

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter;

...

public SecurityConfiguration(TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter) {
    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, TokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(You log out success handler goes here)
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

}
```

}

And your TokenAuthenticationFilter class will do the token authenticity for every request.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter;

...

public SecurityConfiguration(TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter) {
    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, TokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(You log out success handler goes here)
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

   }
 }
```

Comment: I see what you want to say, but this will not solve the problem , in this case all the request will go through the TokenAuthenticationFilter. But what i want is to apply this token authentification just for a url pattern `/api/**` , and apply another authentification (email,password) for the other requests

Comment: So in that case this answer might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46239996/4801359